# Deploying with sfdx but no component is deployed with no errors

Tags: salesforcedx, sfdx-error, mdapideploy

My actual problem is that I am trying to deploy my package with sfdx using following command :

```
//to create a folder of only the specified element of the package.xml
sfdx force:source:convert -x manifest/deployment.xml --outputdir deployment

//create a zip using terminal
tar.exe -a -c -f deployment.zip deployment

//to deploy the manually zip folder
sfdx force:mdapi:deploy --zipfile deployment.zip --checkonly
```

Validation is successful on the org but with 0/0 components. No error displayed also.

[image]
Sfdx is not telling me if something is wrong or not in the zip folder or the elements.

May may be the issue or how to get any hidden errors if any ?

It does not seem that the zip folder is incorrect either, because if it is NOT in the correct format , sfdx generate this error :

[image]

Here is the details of the zip internal folder :

[image]

Comment: Couple of things spring to mind, `manifest/deployment.xml` should be `package.xml`. Assuming that is not the issue, are you able to deploy using the `deployment` folder rather than `deployment.zip`? What is the contents of `deployment.zip`?

Comment: in the deployment folder, sfdx generate the package.xml file as required, and this is used by sfdx. Else how to deploy using the folder and not the zip ?

Comment: Where are you looking that you see 0/0 components? have you run `sfdx force:mdapi:deploy:report`? FWIW, I had no issues running through the same commands as you (and same file/folder names). Are you on the latest version or what metadata do you have in your `manifest/deployment.xml`?

Comment: @vanessen I was trying to establish if there were problems with the .zip file. I think you can use `--deploydir` to point directly to your `deployment` folder thus ruling out any issues with the .zip. From the screen shots you've supplied, it looks ok. Second screenshot appears to show a GACK so I would report to SF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got to solve the issue. It was related to the zip file. I generate the zip file as follows :

```
tar.exe -a -c -f deployment.zip deployment
```

I cannot explain why generating a zip file like this will deploy 0 components on salesforce. When running the following command by deploying the whole folder , it works :

```
sfdx force:mdapi:deploy -d deployment
```

I will no more use zip file for deployment now

Answer (score 2):

Uncovering the actual GACK error from internal Salesforce logs,

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: malformed input off : 35, length :
> 1

This is a known issue with the metadata API if you have  Umlauts (like "ü", "ä" and "ö") in your metadata files. There is an internal bug logged for this with reference number W-8928985.

There is no workaround except finding those characters and getting rid of it.

The core issue is because of a bug in [JDK](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4415733). I believe jdk does not support German Umlauts in the file name. That's why if we use the filename in the zip file, it's corrupted.